# Is book value a meaningless metric for American REITs?

Tags: assets, reit

Is it true that US REITs do not re-value their real estate net-worth every year? If yes, then how the "total asset value" is calculated?

Comment: In the current market ,I took my losses and sold all my REITS. If they go bankrupt it does not matter what the total asset value is.

Comment: @blacksmith37 saying that the current market is bad doesn't apply to how the total asset values is calculated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Book value for REITs are just another data point to take with a grain of salt. I wouldn't call them meaningless, as they provide another anchor with which to benchmark a portfolio of similar REITS. Not one you want to use by itself to make investment decisions, but an anchor nonetheless.

Real estate is neither fungible, nor liquid that way a share is on a stock exchange i.e. there is no quick way to mark the assets to market. Any re-valuations (even if that was done) would be theoretical because "I think this is worth $x" means much less than "Give it to me and i'll pay $x". Hence, the book value of a REIT is not as actionable as say another company holding its entire value in cash - two extreme ends of a liquidity/price transparency spectrum. All anyone can do is estimate value in the absence of a transaction.

A good way to think of a REIT's book value is like the value at which property appraised and taxed. It is just an estimation. When houses finally sells, there is no clearly defined relationship between the appraised value by the state or county and the sale price. Sometimes its higher, sometimes its lower and sometimes its right in the ballpark.

A key difference with REIT book values is that this "subjective until sold" price is provided to you by the REIT, not some third party. Yes, they have auditors and the SEC...but people still play games especially when you consider that it is based on what they thought was a fair price some time ago, less some measure of depreciation. The duration of the portfolio also contributes to eroding the expected accuracy of book value over time. Was the asset bought 1 month ago? 1 year? 5? This matters both from the perspective of how much the market has drifted since the deal, and how much depreciation has been applied to the asset. You can see how the book value would tell two totally different but wrong stories for

1. Assets bought in 2006 (mkt peak) and evaluated in 2008 (mkt trough). Book value would likely be too high
2. Assets bought in 2009 and evaluated in 2019. Book value would likely be too low.

I would suggest using operating income from the assets to back into the value of their holdings i.e. if you assume 5% is a reasonable cap rate for a specific REITs asset-class (retail, residential etc), and their most recent operating income was $x million, then you can quickly back into your subjective asset value. Deducting any liabilities or impairments and adding any premium (mgmt, tenant credit quality etc) you deem fit should get you to your own subjective net asset value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that is exactly how I had decided to calculate 'net asset value'